# Send E-mail to User When Account is Activated though Django Admin Application

Tags: django, admin

Is there a way to send an e-mail to a user when their account is activated through the Django admin application? I can do it independently of the Django admin application but I want the admin to be signed in before they activate a user. Is there a way to achieve this without customizing the Django admin application code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @Foobar, how does your activation process work?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can override the [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#django.forms.ModelForm) and add the email sending logic in `clean` method. Also use that modelform in the `Admin` class. For example:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    manual_activation = forms.BooleanField()  # a flag which determines if the user should be manually activated

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


    def clean(self):
        manual_activation = self.cleaned_data.pop('manual_activation', False)  
        if manual_activation:
             # send_email logics

        return self.cleaned_data


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = UserForm
```

What will happen is that, in the User admin page, if you click on an user it will show an extra field in the form, named `manual_activation`. If you check and save the form, then in clean method, you can catch the value of `manual_activation` and based on that send email.